# How to call a step (doing revert) if any previous step fails?

Tags: argo-workflows

I have the Argo `WorkflowTemplate` which has `n` steps.

I want to call `last step` only if any of the previous step fails.

**Example**: In a 5 steps templates, if `2nd` fails, skip `3` and `4` and only call `5` since its a revert step. If all are passed, don't call `5th` because there is no need to revert.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define a workflow [exit handler](https://github.com/argoproj/argo-workflows/blob/master/examples/exit-handlers.yaml) to run after all the other steps.

By adding a `when` condition, you can make sure the exit handler runs if and only if one of the previous steps failed.

Comment: nice. looking into both. regarding the when condition how do we check the success/failure status ? {{steps.step1.status.failed}} >0 doesn't seem to work

Comment: @colossal you won't be able to access `steps` variables from the exit handler unless they're marked global. You can use `when: "{{workflow.status}} != Succeeded"` to detect a failed workflow.